# How to move a record within a collectionproxy in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

In my rails app I have a collectionproxy that is an array (I think) of records.  I want to take a record from the middle of the array and put it at the beginning.  I don't know the position of the item, but I can find it using an attribute on user model.  It seems like some methods aren't available to use on a collectionproxy.

I tried:

```
user_images = user.images
user_images.insert(0, user_images.delete(user.images.find_by_id(user.primary_image_id))
```

but got an error that I gave 2 arguments but it expected 1.  I'm guessing because the insert method that is used on arrays isnt the same method that is used on collectionproxies.  What's the best way to do this?

Edit:  I just need this to display the items in the view, I don't need to change at the database level.

Comment: You need to change it in the data base level or just to show in the view?

Comment: @sravan just to show in the view

Comment: which Item you want to place it at begining?

Comment: @Sravan I need the image whose `id` matches `user.primary_image_id`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As very few methods are available for collection proxy, first change the collection proxy to array and then manipulate it.

Here is the code to do so,

```
 user_images = user.images.to_a //converted collection to array
 user_images.unshift(user_images.detect{ |image| image.id == user.primary_image_id}).uniq //used unshift
 puts user_images
```

The magic we have done here is `detect` the images that's the primary image of the user and `unshift` into array
**The unshift adds the object in the beginning.**
Now remove the duplicated oject which is already there at someplace by using uniq.

That's it your required objects comes first into the array and you can use this in the view as active record collection is used.

Comment: So converting to array just saves it temporarily for the view and the order in activerecord remains unchanged?

Comment: Yes, order in the active record means in db?

Comment: you can display the primary image first in the view by converting to array

Comment: I ended up using insert instead of unshift like in my question, but the converting to array did the trick.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like there's currently no way to add to the beginning of a `CollectionProxy`. The `prepend` and `sort` methods were removed. Here's the API for the deprecated `prepend` method:
http://apidock.com/rails/v4.2.1/ActiveRecord/Associations/CollectionProxy/prepend

You could re-think this slightly, and use the `append` or `<<` operator along with `delete` to copy elements to the end of the collection, and delete them from the middle. It's not ideal, but it might be a workaround until you have a better solution.

Comment: Basically, you'd have to start at the beginning and move everything to the end, skipping the element that you wanted at the start. You'll end up with the same order of elements, except the "skipped" one should be at the beginning.